GStreamer pipeline writing UDP stream frames to JPEG images, but some frames have scattered pixels
I have written a C++ code using a GStreamer pipeline that takes a UDP stream as input and writes the frames into JPEG images. However, some of the output images have scattered pixels and are also blurr, and I'm not sure what's causing this issue. The input video which used in udp stream is clear and high-quality video and it is 1fps, H264 (baseline) video. We are using ubuntu 20.04 on Virtual Box.
1st code is a server code which creates udp stream from input video.
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    gst_init(&argc, &argv);

    // path to your video file
    const char *video_path = "./data/test_video.mp4";
    // the host address
    const char *host_address = "224.1.1.1";
    //the port
    int port = 5000;

    GstElement *pipeline = gst_parse_launch(
        g_strdup_printf("filesrc location=%s ! qtdemux ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 ! udpsink host=%s port=%d auto-multicast=true", video_path, host_address, port), NULL);
    
}

then 2nd code consumes this stream and write frames into jpeg images.
static GstFlowReturn new_sample(GstElement *sink, gpointer user_data) {
    static int frame_count = 1;
    GstSample *sample;
    GstBuffer *buffer;
    GstMapInfo map;

    g_signal_emit_by_name(sink, "pull-sample", &sample);
    if (sample) {
        buffer = gst_sample_get_buffer(sample);
        gst_buffer_map(buffer, &map, GST_MAP_READ);

        std::string directory = "output/";
        std::string filename = directory + "frame_" + std::to_string(frame_count) + ".jpg";
        std::ofstream file(filename, std::ios::binary);
        file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(map.data), map.size);
        file.close();
        frame_count++;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    gst_init(&argc, &argv);

    const gchar *pipeline_str =
        "udpsrc multicast-group=224.1.1.1 auto-multicast=true port=5000 "
        "caps=\"application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264\" "
        "! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! videorate ! video/x-raw, framerate=1/1 ! jpegenc ! appsink name=sink sync=false";

}


The code correctly writes the frames to the specified path. However, some of the output JPEG images contain scattered pixels and artifacts.
Any insights into what might be causing these issues and how to resolve them would be greatly appreciated.
This is the Jpeg image we get from our pipeline. I have put bounding box on the area where pixels are scattered
This the expected image

This is far from a [mre]. Unless you factor in packet loss, the transmission of h.264 packets over UDP will not cause a degradation. Did you play with the quality attribute of the jpegenc filter?

I have edited my query. I have added two images, one is output image from the  pipeline. I have highlighted the area where pixels are scattered, and second image is the expected image. In my pipeline I have not used any quality parameter.

You may try adding h264parse in sender pipeline between qtdemux and rtph264pay. The former one may output H264 in avc format while the latter only expects byte-stream format.
Also try specifying caps after udpsrc instead of its caps property.
See if it works from terminal with gst-launch on localhost for before investigating UDP network issues.

I used wireshark to measure packet loss, but it shows 0% drop and displayed 100% and total packets 80368 . I also used a filter with checksum.status=="Bad" but It doesn't show any packet whose checksum is bad , each packet has checksum status as Good.

As per you suggestion I added h264parse in sender pipeline and also tried specifying the caps after udpsrc. Now my modified pipeline:     Sender pipeline:   GstElement *pipeline = gst_parse_launch(
g_strdup_printf("filesrc location=%s ! qtdemux ! h264parse ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 ! udpsink host=%s port=%d auto-multicast=true",
video_path, host_address, port),
NULL
);

Receiver pipeline:     const gchar *pipeline_str =
"udpsrc multicast-group=224.1.1.1 auto-multicast=true port=5000 "
"! application/x-rtp, media=video, clock-rate=90000, encoding-name=H264 "
"! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! videorate "
"! video/x-raw, framerate=1/1 ! jpegenc ! appsink name=sink sync=false";   but I don't observed any improvement , the scattered pixels are still there

I have tried launching it on localhost also , I observe scattered pixels there as well.
